# $F(x,y,z)=3x{\bf{i}}-4y{\bf{j}}+5z{\bf{k}}$ is a vector field, $S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$ is an outward oriented surface. Find $\iiint\text{div}\ F\ dV$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$F(x,y,z)=3x\textbf{i}-4y\textbf{j}+5z\textbf{k}$ is the vector field and $S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$ is an outward oriented surface. Evaluate $\iiint\ \text{div}\ F\ dV.$

I have been trying to solve this question but couldn't put my head around it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is fairly straightforward. Did you try calculating $\operatorname{div} F$ ?

Comment: I did but couldn't proceed! Any help or hint

Comment: Well what is it?

Comment: I don't actual get the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$div F= 3-4+5=4$, so the volume integral is just $4V$, where $V$ is the volume of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

By divergence theorem, $\iiint_S div(F) dV=\iint_{\partial S}(F\cdot n)\;dA$, where $\partial S$ denotes the boundary of S. Pick a parametrization for S: $\Bbb X=(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (x=a\sin\theta\cos\phi,y=a\sin\theta\sin\phi,z=a\cos\theta)$, where $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi, 0\lt \phi\lt 2\pi$. We may then write $n\;dA=\Bbb X_{\theta} \times \Bbb X_{\phi} \;d\theta d\phi$. Computing gives $\Bbb X_{\theta}=(a\cos\theta\cos\phi, a\cos\theta\sin\phi,  -a\sin\theta),  \Bbb X_{\phi}=(-a\sin\theta\sin\phi,a\sin\theta\cos\phi,  0)$ and $X_{\theta} \times \Bbb X_{\phi}=(a^2\sin^2\theta\cos\phi,a^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi,a^2\cos\theta\cos\phi)$.
Hence we have $$\iiint_S div(F) dV=\iint_{\partial S}(3a^3\sin^3\theta\cos^2\phi-4a^3\sin^3\theta\sin^2\phi+5a^3\cos^2\theta\cos\phi) \;d\theta d\phi$$ which may be computed by ordinary means.

Note: Given $F=(a(x,y,z),b(x,y,z),c(x,y,z))$, the divergence of F is $div (F)=a_x+b_y+c_z$, where the subscript denotes partial derivative with respect to the variable in the subscript.

Comment: This is an overkill, the divergence is just a constant.